# apply linear-gadient to html progress bar based on progress bar color

Tags: html, css

I have following code that applies linear-grandient to progress bar.

currently it shows gradient on same color `rgb(33, 177, 89)`

How can i keep the progress bar color and apply linear-gradient on it?

I am trying to show gradient on first progress bar having color red and second blue.

```
<div style="color:red;">
  <progress style=background:currentColor max="100" value="85" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="75" tabindex="-1">
  </progress>
</div>

<div style="color:blue;">
  <progress style=background:currentColor max="100" value="85" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="75" tabindex="-1">
  </progress>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nick1111/3bLgLr9h/95/

Answer (score 0):

So the HTML tag won't naturally pull in parent data like a scripting language might. You actually have to define CSS classes that will change the appearance based on the class applied.

```
<style type="text/css">

.row { margin:20px 0; }

progress {
    border: 0;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 100px;
} 

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(33, 177, 89, .1), rgba(33, 177, 89, 1));
}

progress.red::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, .1), rgba(255, 0, 0, 1));
}

progress.blue::-webkit-progress-value {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 255, .1), rgba(0, 0, 255, 1));
}
```

```
<div class="row">
    <progress class="red" max="100" value="85" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="75" tabindex="-1"></progress>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <progress class="blue" max="100" value="85" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="75" tabindex="-1"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Stevens. User can pass color as input so it can be anything. We cant create classes for all colors right? Is there any way we can apply gradient on any color use choose?

Comment: So you are wanting the user to be able to select any color and then apply that color to the slider. Is that correct?